# Can boss introduce company handbook and make employees sign?

Tags: contracts

I have a contract with the company i work for and have been with them five years. Recently the boss wrote a company handbook, many of the points in it I have to disagree with - they also contradict my contract. Do I have to sign?

Comment: What is it that you are signing, that you agree with the handbook or simply that you have read it and you acknowledge being cognizant of the contents?

Comment: They asked for one or the other.

Comment: No they cant make you sign, but they also could choose to let you go for refusing to follow their company policy.

Comment: That very much depends on the country. In most of Europe, a contract is a contract and cannot be unilaterally changed. I can't give myself a raise, for instance. Of course, the boss often can make some or all raises conditional on accepting the company handbook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You clarified further that you have the option to sign to indicate either that:

- you are in agreement with the contents of the handbook, where the fact is that you aren't, or
- you have read the handbook and you are cognizant of the contents of the handbook.

You want to make it clear that you are merely signing that you've read the handbook and you acknowledge being cognizant of the contents, even if you have to scribble the sentence on the signature page - You DON'T want to commit to anything more than that at the moment. You should make your boss aware - if possible, before you sign anything at all - that specific passages in the handbook are in contradiction with various terms of your contract, and let's hear what he says about how he intends to resolve or reconcile the discrepancies

Answer (score 6):

Asking about the signature is missing the most important point.

**If you are being presented with a handbook which describes conditions of employment different from those in your contract, you need to discuss those changes in a serious way with your boss right now.** It's completely wrong to wait until the issue comes up to try and argue that the policy doesn't apply to you because you didn't sign it.

For example, if your contract says you get 20 days vacation, and the new handbook says everyone gets 15 days, go to your boss and point out that it's a change, and that its hurting you. Be specific and ask what you are going to get for agreeing to go down to 15 days vacation. If he says that the policy won't apply to you, make sure you get that in writing.

It is sometimes worthwhile getting a lawyer to look at anything you sign at work. If there are substantial changes to the terms of your employment, this is probably a good time. Get a few colleagues together and hire a lawyer for an hour. Split several ways the cost isn't that much.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Vietnhi's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/34866/9264), but would qualify it with this:

Do not sign the signature page.  There may be verbiage there that you don't understand, or do not intend to agree to.  Instead, create a document (letter) that has a date, saying that you have received a copy of the handbook (and specify the date of the handbook and its version number, if applicable).  Then mention that your contract is what the governing document of your employment has been and will continue to be.

Be prepared to discuss the specific conflicts between the handbook and the contract, and also the parts of the handbook you cannot accept the terms of.  Be prepared to renegotiate your contract.

Be aware, however, that your boss may choose to exercise the exit clause of your contract.

I've fought this battle.  I won, but in the end, it caused so much acrimony with the VP who wrote the policies it became easier just to leave.

Comment: This is definitely something I would advise doing. The thing about signing a "I have read and am aware of this" signature is that your boss could use it to try to mean "I will follow these guidelines" instead. Unfortunately since none of us a lawyers, this is probably the safest way to approach it outside of contacting one.

Comment: The reconciliation part between the two docs has to be done - I'd be pretty peeved if I were asked to sign that I am in agreement with two legal documents that are in contradiction with each other. In addition, a contract is a mutual agreement, No one should be changing the terms of a mutual agreement without the consent of the other party.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - Exactly the reason I would *NOT* sign the signature page of the handbook.

Comment: @WesleyLong I doesn't cost you anything to sign that you have read the document. Signing that you agree with it when you don't - that's something else.